# Changing only one row to column in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

So the data frame is

```
computer status   count
   A       on      45
           off     44
   B       on      34
           off     32
           rmt_off 12
   C       on      23
           off     23
           rmt_off 2
```

I performed

```
df.set_index('status').T
```

which gave me

```
status     on   off   on   off   rmt_off   on   off   rmt_off
computer   A          B                   C
Count      45   45    34   32    12        23   23    2
```

Expected Output:

```
Computer   On   off   Rmt_off 
  A        45   45     NaN
  B        34   32     12
  C        23   23     2
```

How to make the values to be presented like this?
Is there any built-in functions available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) if `MultiIndex` one column `DataFrame`:

```
print (df.index)
MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['off', 'on', 'rmt_off']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2]],
           names=['computer', 'status'])

print (df['count'].unstack())
status     off    on  rmt_off
computer                     
A         44.0  45.0      NaN
B         32.0  34.0     12.0
C         23.0  23.0      2.0
```

EDIT: Need replace empty strings to `NaN`s with forward filling, last use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df['computer'] = df['computer'].mask(df['computer'] == '').ffill()
df = df.pivot('computer','status', 'count')
```

Comment: it is not multiindex

Answer (score 2):

Try to fix your dataframe by `replace` and `ffill`, then we can apply `pivot` to your original df, change the long format to wide

```
df=df.replace('',np.nan).ffill()
df.pivot(*df.columns)
Out[437]: 
status     off    on  rmt_off
computer                     
A         44.0  45.0      NaN
B         32.0  34.0     12.0
C         23.0  23.0      2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try df.unstack(level=1).

`df.unstack(level=1)
Out[84]: 
  count

    off   on
A   NaN  NaN
B   NaN  NaN
C   NaN  NaN`